# set a process open file max to maximum (in linux)

Tags: linux, limit, max, setrlimit

Is there anyway to set the (hard limit) open-file-max (setrlimit, RLIMIT_NOFILE) to the maximum?

suppose that the pid of the process is zero (root).  I just want to increase the
RLIMIT_NOFILE to the maximum, but I don't know what is the maximum value.

(RLIM_INFINITY does not work anyway).

Comment: You mean uid, not pid, right? There is no pid 0.